Confusion about the solutions of non-exact differential equation using integrating factors
Suppose have a differential equation $M(x,y) + N(x,y)y'=0$ where $M_y \neq N_x$, we can use an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$ to convert this equation to $\mu(x,y)M(x,y) + \mu(x,y)N(x,y)y'=0$ to make it exact and find a $\psi(x,y)=c$ that satisfies the equation $\mu(x,y)M(x,y) + \mu(x,y)N(x,y)y'=0$. My textbook stops here and says that this solution is also the solution of the original equation but how can we be sure that this is also a solution to the original non-exact equation as well?

Well, if $\mu\neq 0$ then the solution must be the same, isn't it?

Oh yeah, we can rewrite it as $\mu(x,y)(M(x,y)+N(x,y)y')=0$, and then as you have said if $\mu\neq0$, the solution would also satisfy the original equation. Thanks!
